# ghidra returning wrong function address

Tags: android, ghidra, memory, frida

I am reverse engineering a android app shared library (.so file) and I am trying to use frida to hook a non exported native function
I am using this hook

```
const ghidraImageBase = 0x00100000; 
const moduleName = "libclient.so";
const moduleBaseAddress = Module.findBaseAddress(moduleName);
const ghidraFunction = 0x0168a7c8;
const functionRealAddress = moduleBaseAddress.add(ghidraFunction - ghidraImageBase);

Interceptor.attach(functionRealAddress, {
    onEnter: function(args) {

        console.log("function called");

    },
    onLeave: function(ignored) {}
});
```

However function called is never logged even though the function is getting called
I am pretty sure something is wrong with the addresses so I tried hooking into a exported function using the address I got from ghidra

[image: ![pic]

which is `0x014ccd08` and ghidra image base is equal to `0x00100000` meaning the offset of the function should be `0x014ccd08` - `0x00100000` = `0x013ccd08`
however when I run

```
console.log("moduleBaseAddress:" + Module.findBaseAddress("libclient.so"))


Module.enumerateExports("libclient.so", {
    onMatch: function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'function') {
            if (e.name == "Java_exported_function etc...") {
                console.log("Function found");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
            }
        }
    },
    onComplete: function() {}
});
```

the above code execution result is

```
moduleBaseAddress:0xb6900000
Function recognized by name
{"type":"function","name":"Java_exported_function...","address":"0xb755b9e1"}
```

the .so library is loaded at `0xb6900000` and the function address is at `0xb755b9e1` meaning the function offset is `0xb755b9e1` - `0xb6900000` = `0x00c5b9e1`
entirely different from the `0x013ccd08` I found earlier.

1. Can this issue be from the ghidra settings?
2. How can I get the correct offset from ghidra?

Comment: Do you use an emulator or a real device? If you are using an emulator make sure not to use an x86 image with an armv7/arm64 app. The integrated arm emulation is incompatible with frida.

Comment: i am using a x86 image however frida does support hooking of native functions with arm translation as stated by its creator in this issue https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/1567 come to think of it now i dont know which version of arm library is being loaded since it has both arm64 and armeabi-v7a and the one i reversed on ghidra is arm64 is there a way to tell which one is loaded into memory

Comment: I can only recommend to you to use a real device or an ARM image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i decompiled the wrong library the emulator i was running is 32bit where as the library i decompiled in ghidra is 64bit decompiling the 32bit lib i get the correct offsests same as expected ones